# SAML RSA FIM (EMC) cant verify signature

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am implementing SSO as the Service provider and the ID provider is RSA FIM aka EMC.  I am successfully sending them an AuthN request and receiving a saml response but i just can seem to verify the signature.  They have sent me their actual .cer file and currently i pull it up directly and grab the public key.  Then pass that to the check signature function.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated and let me know if any clarification is needed.  I'm not getting any errors just a false on the check signature method every time no matter what.  I've tried changing the encoding from utf-8 to ASCII.  To no avail nothing seems to work and im going mad! haha

This is the logic:

```
/*Get XML in previous function and build saml doc.*/

byte[] base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(samlResponse);
samlXml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes); 

_SamlDocument = new XmlDocument();
_SamlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
_SamlDocument.LoadXml(samlXml);


/*Verify Function*/
        public Boolean Verify()
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (_SamlDocument == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid XML Doc.");

            // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
            // the XML document class.
            SamlSignedXml signedXml = new SamlSignedXml(_SamlDocument, "ID");

            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(_SamlDocument.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace("ds", SamlSignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);

            // Find the "Signature" node and create a new
            // XmlNodeList object.
            XmlNodeList nodeList =  _SamlDocument.SelectNodes("//ds:Signature", manager);

            // Throw an exception if no signature was found.
            if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
            }

            // This example only supports one signature for
            // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception
            // if more than one signature was found.
            if (nodeList.Count >= 2)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
            }

            // Load the first <signature> node.
            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

            var bVerified = false;

            /*Pulls in .cer file directly from brand cert string which is a file location.*/
            X509Certificate2 brandCert = new X509Certificate2(brandCertificateString);
            bVerified = signedXml.CheckSignature(brandCert.PublicKey.Key);

            return bVerified;
        }
```

/*Sample saml response that is sent.*/

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" Destination="_removed information_" ID="c9c96cd8c3e6cdef4d5c1d976968d347" InResponseTo="_5990ada8-e69f-4e66-90f1-d7e96dafbe4f" IssueInstant="2013-05-23T18:52:24Z" Version="2.0"><saml:Issuer>_removed information_</saml:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference URI="#c9c96cd8c3e6cdef4d5c1d976968d347">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>Bi9EXd/yvWKHV7Hvc8tB3ddmDW8=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
eCwiyItypMUOW9dUs8nEx5ufKRZfwCcDKTvkEYa4UQA048N9Sno4/tPJICenhV/5SCjnMSR4wx5q
FKcS5FiMK0q1JFl3qeDzUwl1zH1kqJQjS1fUatC7SKvCRRAI25nNapGT/4DZiaTmEt3tzf/o36b0
HHyuLkFI3RlaEtzJ91vE7uH5dOI6GPAaG9p8rtBDXvNWhsGnuYIaJog8MUUXuD3wAudNAhMvuBsq
rjsR0GW4x92k60lbMcus+qHNtpZyT96LyKVW5MF9HklQOkEW0ip8AJD3u6n3RTAtQnmoIJIOzSzH
15pnmOJJVWzD7UqnWjAZIjWR7NYiDBSpggYtvA==
</ds:SignatureValue>
</ds:Signature><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"></samlp:StatusCode></samlp:Status><saml:Assertion ID="d26d141cea5a9a5c912916a534957e04" IssueInstant="2013-05-23T18:52:24Z" Version="2.0"><saml:Issuer>_removedinformation_</saml:Issuer><saml:Subject><saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">_removed information_</saml:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_5990ada8-e69f-4e66-90f1-d7e96dafbe4f" NotOnOrAfter="2013-05-23T18:53:24Z" Recipient="_removed information_"></saml:SubjectConfirmationData></saml:SubjectConfirmation></saml:Subject><saml:Conditions NotBefore="2013-05-23T18:51:54Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-05-23T18:53:24Z"><saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:Audience>_removed information_</saml:Audience></saml:AudienceRestriction></saml:Conditions><saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2013-05-23T18:52:23Z" SessionIndex="d26d141cea5a9a5c912916a534957e04"><saml:SubjectLocality Address="10.96.40.30" DNSName="localhost.localdomain"></saml:SubjectLocality><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Kerberos</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement><saml:AttributeStatement xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><saml:Attribute FriendlyName="UserName" Name="UserName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"><saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">_removed information_</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute></saml:AttributeStatement></saml:Assertion></samlp:Response>
```

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer thanks to Keith's from here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/6139044/778401).  Using the name managers to get down to the signature nodes worked perfectly and got me a clean signature verification.  I had to modify slightly so that signature was pulled from response node instead of assertion node but it worked beautifully.  Thank you so much Keith!

```
// load a new XML document
var assertion = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
assertion.LoadXml("The SAML XML that you were sent");

// use a namespace manager to avoid the worst of xpaths
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(assertion.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("samlp", @"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
ns.AddNamespace("asrt", @"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
ns.AddNamespace("dsig", @"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

// get nodes down to the signature
var responseNode = assertion.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response", ns);
var assertionNode = responseNode.SelectSingleNode("asrt:Assertion", ns);
var signNode = assertionNode.SelectSingleNode("dsig:Signature", ns);

// load the XML signature
var signedXml = new SignedXml(assertion.DocumentElement);
signedXml.LoadXml(signNode as XmlElement);

// get the certificate, basically:
//     signedXml.KeyInfo[0].Certificates[0]
// ...but with added casting
var certificate = GetFirstX509Certificate(signedXml);

// check the key and signature match
bool isSigned = signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate, true);
```