# ADFS, WS-FED Passive and SAML token verification

Tags: x509certificate, saml-2.0, adfs, ws-federation

I am working on a web application which should authenticate users via ADFS. WS-FED Passive was chosen as the simplest and fastest to implement.

The setup went smooth and the application seemed working: a user is first redirected to the the Identity Provider service, enters username/password and in case of success a SAML token is POSTed back to the web app.

Here where I get confused: a SAML token can be validated via the Signature and X509Certificate data which are contained in it.

However, what is the proper mechanism to verify that the token was POSTed by *the* Identity Provider service, not by a third-party which also posesses the certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAML: Why is the certificate within the Signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703301/saml-why-is-the-certificate-within-the-signature)

Comment: Only the public key is in the signature and nobody except the identity provider should have the private key. But whether that public key is one that you trust is a separate lookup you have to do. In SAML2-P there's a metadata standard where your SP can query the IDP up-front to get the list of certs that it will use. ADFS supports this metadata standard.